# What is the highest spatial frequency that can occur in an image? And the smallest one?

Tags: image-quality, digital, resolution

I searched the information and couldn't find the answer.
I don't understand about this and I don't know how to respond.

Comment: Perhaps a little more context around what you're trying to figure out would be useful. Taking a wild, but maybe slightly educated, guess, are you looking to do some sort of Fourier or other transform-based image analysis. If so, the high frequency you're looking for will depend on your sensor pixel density/size, lens focal length, focus distance, and probably a few other factors. On the low end, zero sounds reasonable, since negative frequencies are really just a mathematical construct.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.